# Do you get the Summoning Pits bounty for killing Phogoth if another party member deals the killing blow?

Tags: destiny

I just got a bounty card to kill Phogoth in the Summoning Pits strike mission on the Moon.
If I play this with a friend and he gets the killing shot, do I still earn the bounty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Kills, exp, missions, patrols, and bounties (if players have the same bounty) will be shared no matter who gets the killing blow. There is no "Kill Stealing" in Destiny (except for maybe missions that require *you* to get X kills by doing a certain thing)

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I already did this once, before I got the bounty, when I was level 12, with a friend who was level 20. It was super difficult and I don't want to do it alone again :)

Comment: just don't stand in the entrance area and he's not as bad... the lower rocks off to the left when you first go in is an excellent place to hang out

Comment: I hid behind the rock down to the left. Me and my buddy alternated between shooting Phogoth and taking out any minions who came to attack us. Worked fairly well. Rock is love, rock is life :)